# Programmatically extract default email account in settings bundle iOS

Tags: ios, ipad, email, nsuserdefaults, settings.bundle

Need very quick help.. When an email is configured in iPad then Settings app will store this account information. Programmatically I want to access this default email account configured in Settings App of the iPad. I just want to know is it yahoo or gmail or any type and possibly the user name.

Is it possible to extract this information programmatically, may be using NSUserDefaults or any other settings or preferences ? Please suggest..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no API nor an NSUserDefaults key that provides the "default" e-mail address. I've read about some third-party APIs that do this that make use of undocumented APIs, but any app making use of these will almost certainly be rejected by Apple upon review after submission. Your best bet is to ask the user which e-mail address they want to use for your app—or, for that matter, if your app simply involves sending an e-mail, use the `MFMailViewComposeViewController` class.

Comment: My purpose is: In my app i want to send an email using MFMailViewComposeViewController and when i am sending I want to make sure it is configured with my company mail account (due to security reasons i must not allow sending email vai gmail account or any public emails). So I have to validate whether the ipad is configured with my company mail id. Is there any alternative for this purpose ?

Comment: If you have multiple e-mail addresses configured on your device, there should be a selectable "From:" field in the MFMailComposeViewController that will allow you to choose the e-mail address to send it from. Unfortunately, there isn't any way in Apple's API to force a specific e-mail address. The selectable "from" field is a part of the API and can't be changed.

Comment: how to access selectable from filed ? Is it possible.. Can you post any sample code for that purpose

Comment: Have a look at this image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/tkgdn.png. It's from a similar question to yours. I've just double checked on my iPad running iOS 6, and the `From` field is absolutely still there within the view controller. It only appears when you have multiple e-mail addresses configured, and because it's built-in to the API, there's no sample code to post.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to access any information about a user's email account settings. You must ask the user to provide the details to your app.

Comment: Are you sure about that?

Comment: @Nicolas Yes, at least no public API.